# JAVA: Greek characters from downloaded HTML file aren't displayed, how can I fix this?

Tags: java, html, character

I'm downloading an HTML file and I need to display it with `System.out.println()`.

The problem is that instead of Greek characters I get rubbish.

I'm using to download the code below to download the HTML file:

```
 URL url = new URL("here goes the link to the html file");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
 String htmlfile = "";
 String temp;
 while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
       htmlfile+= temp;
 }
 System.out.println(htmlfile);
```

Is it possible to fix this problem? Here is a sample of what I get as a result:

```
    <title>Ξ ΟΞ»Ξ·  ΞΞ»Ξ΅ΞΊΟΟΏΟ ΟΏ Ξ΄ΞΉΞΊΟΟΞ±ΞΊΟ ΟΟΟΞΏ</title>
```

All my regional settings on my computer are fine. I can use `System.out.println` to display Greek words directly.
I have a feeling I need to change some locale settings in the `BufferedReader` but I'm not sure how to do it, or whether that's the correct way of approaching this problem.

Somewhat off topic, I have a feeling the above method of downloading the HTML file is really ineffective. For example, when I use `html+=temp`, aren't I basically creating a new `String` instance every time I read a line from the HTML file? This sounds very costly, if you can please suggest me other methods of doing the same thing that is more effective.

Comment: What's costly is when you keep on concatenating `temp` to `htmlFile`. That's `O(n)` time complexity. I would just output `temp` each time it changes: `while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.print(temp);
 }`

Comment: Have you made sure your output stream is in UTF-8?

Comment: tchrist, I didn't know I could do that, I tried the method initially suggested by Joop Eggen and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String encoding = "UTF-8"; // Or "ISO-8859-7"
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), encoding));
```

ISO-8859-1 is the 8-bit encoding used by Greek, UTF-8 the multibyte unicode encoding.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String temp;
while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(temp).append("\n");
    System.out.println(temp);
}
String html = sb.toString();
```

readLine removes the line ending (`\r` old MacOS, `\n` Unix or `\r\n` Windows).

Comment: "ISO-8859-1 is the 8-bit encoding used by Greek" --
As you put in your comment, it's actually ISO-8859-7. +1, though.

Comment: MacOS hasn’t use `\r` since time immemorial.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [content type's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) character set as specified by the response headers.

The below adapts [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) to your problem.

```
URL url = new URL("here goes the link to the html file");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
try {
  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
  // Look at the input connection headers to figure out the character encoding.
  // The contentType is null or a String like "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  String contentType = conn.getContentType();
  // Get the charset from the content type.
  String charset = null;
  if (contentType != null) {
    for (String param : contentType.replace(" ", "").split(";")) {
      if (param.startsWith("charset=")) {
        charset = param.split("=", 2)[1];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // Choose a default that does not depend on the default encoding.
  // It might be best to use the default encoding if the URL is a
  // file: URL.
  if (charset == null) { charset = "UTF-8"; }
  Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, charset);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
  // Read the content from the buffered reader as above.
  // See below.
} finally {
  conn.close();
}
```

> Somewhat off topic, I have a feeling the above method of downloading the HTML file is really ineffective. For example, when I use html+=temp, aren't I basically creating a new String instance every time I read a line from the HTML file?

Yes, the below is a more efficient way to read characters.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] buf = new char[4096];
for (int nRead; (nRead = br.read(buf)) > 0;) {
  sb.append(buf, 0, nRead);
}
String html = sb.toString();
```

You can read the `Content-length` header via `conn.getHeaderField("Content-length")` to get a hint at the size of the content, to pre-size the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Plus for the `getContentType()`; could use `getContentEncoding()` too.

Comment: @JoopEggen, What does content encoding have to do with charset?  Doesn't that distinguish between chunked encoding vs gzip vs other encoding forms that have nothing to do with byte <-> char mappings?